# Uncaught ReferenceError: ORYX is not defined

Tags: angular, oryx

I am using angular4.

I kept getting this in the console when there is rest call to remote server either when there is json returned or SVG returned.

This is not happening always. But it does happen.

Anyone know what caused this?

Something do with SVG?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more information.

Comment: OK. Added a snapshot of the error message.

Comment: What code causes this error?